# One positive definite matrix optimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, positive-definite

$\underset{X}{\text{maximize}}$ $ \;\text{min}(\lambda_{\text{min}}(R-X),\; \lambda_{\text{min}}(S - X^{-1})) $

subject to $ \;R \succ0,\; S\succ 0,\; X \succ 0,\;R-X \succ 0,\; S-X^{-1} \succ 0$

where $R,S$ are positive definite matrix that are known and fixed, operator $\lambda_{\text{min}}$ takes the minimum eigenvalue of its target matrix.

I was wondering if the optimized value is taken when $R-X = S-X^{-1}$ just like the scalar case? Thank you.

Comment: You may expect $\lambda_\min(R-X)=\lambda_\min(S - X^{-1})$, but not the whole matrices.

Comment: Could you please give the proof? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that all three matrices are variables?

Comment: What do you mean? They are all positive definite matrices. And $R$ and $S$ are known matrices, the problem is to find $X$ that maximizes the objective function.

Comment: @facebook-1536745818 it was unclear, which matrix is subject to maximization and which is fixed/given.

Comment: It has been edited. Thanks.